# Table of code listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I'm using the listings package to put a box around some source code in a document and also to provide some syntax hilighting. Is there an easy way that I could create a table of contents which just listed the code listings? I have already used the figure listing for actual figures and I would rather not mix figures and code listings. Is there perhaps a way I could build two distinct figures collections?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One could use the `\lstlistoflistings` macro that is part of the `listings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\section{foo}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A listing}]
    Some source code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compared to the solution of stimms, could you say which one would be nicer? Defining this `code` environment looks more consistent to `table` and `figure`.

Answer (score 14):

I figured this out. What I did was

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{code}[Code Listing][List of Code Listings] 
\begin{document}
...
\listofcodes
...
\begin{code}
\begin{lstlisting}
    Some source code
\end{lstlisting}
\caption[This here is a caption]{caption}
\end{code}
```

This creates a table of blocks of code. Super nifty.

Answer (score -1):

combining [stimms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4481/stimms)'s and [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s solution
I did this:

- use no extra environment
- call `lstlistings` "Code"
- call `lstlistoflistings` "List of Code Snippets"

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code} % adjusts Listings caption and reference lst
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Code Snippets}
\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\section{foo}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A code snippet}]
    Some source code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

A code snippet
[image: lstlistings]

The list of all code snippets
[image]