# Equivalent of table of contents for figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing a heavy document, which contains more than a hundred figures, all enclosed within a figure environment, and all labeled as well for correct referencing. At the end of the document, I need to create a figure content, which lists the figures according to their page number. I was wondering if there was any package or set of lines, that would get me this result, or do I really have to type the name of the figures one by one?!

Thank you very much,

Josh

Comment: may be `\listoffigures` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Most likely, you mean `\listoffigures` and is advised in any introduction (!!!) to LaTeX ;-)

Comment: Thanks! it seems to be the thing I need. One other question, i have a list of listings to be listed (in my cases, a bunch of programs), is there a similar line that would get me to this same result?

Comment: @Josh Concerning the list of listings, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28716/36296

Comment: @Josh: Please don't ask one question after another in the same question, even if it is so easy to answer like your question here

Answer (score 2):

It may be a little bit confusing, but `\tableofcontents` is a deviating name from the bunch of `\listof...` commands.

If the package author does not have a particular sense of humour he/she will choose a sensible name for the list command, i.e.

- `\listoffigures` for the list of ... well, figures
- `\listoftables`  for ... you guess already, tables
- `\lstlistoflistings` from `listings` is a little bit unusually named

New `\listof...` commands for inclusions of the relevant files can be generated with `\newlistof` from `tocloft`, for example.

From the comment by Johannes_B: `tocbasic` and the `float` package define automatic list - of - commands as well, individual packages provide their own `\listof... versions for their`list of something` features.

Comment: `tocbasic`  also offers the feature, `newfloat` can do it too.