# How to create my own caption type with \DeclareCaptionType on memoir class?

Tags: floats, captions, environments, memoir

On the question [How to create a box with caption and label like a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306568/how-to-create-a-box-with-caption-and-label-like-a-float), they teach how to create your own caption with the `caption` package command `\DeclareCaptionType`, but it not seems to be working with memoir class: [memoir class with subcaption and hyperref packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18931/memoir-class-with-subcaption-and-hyperref-packages)

Then I tried loading `\usepackage{capt-of}` instead of `caption`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx,newfloat}

\DeclareCaptionType{InfoBox}

\begin{document}

    \fboxsep=8pt\relax
    \fboxrule=2pt\relax
    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\centering
      \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}}\par
      \captionof{InfoBox}{Here is my caption\label{fg:A}}
    \end{center}

    \begin{InfoBox}[ht]
    \centering
    \fbox{\centering\medskip
      \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-B}}\par
      \caption{Here is my caption\label{fg:B}}
    \end{InfoBox}

\end{document}
```

But still creating errors:

```
test3.tex:9: Undefined control sequence 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
...
```

On line 14 there is the `\DeclareCaptionType` command for the `caption` package. How can it be used with the memoir class?

Comment: The `caption` package works for me, as well with `hyperref`, the linked question  about the `memoir, caption, hyperref` - Problem has an addendum by Axel Sommerfeldt, the author of `caption`, that this problem has gone.

Comment: But when I load both of them, I still got a big warning: `Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class. To prepare we will now reset all captioning macros and configurations to kernel defaults, and then let the caption package take over. Please remember to use the caption package interfaces in order to configure your captions.` Why show such thing every time I build my document? I can just silence this strange text?

Comment: It is a *Warning*, nothing more or less. `caption` is meant to improve ... `captions` ;-)

Comment: Well, it is only warning I have on my document. I never had to silence any warnings before, I just fixed whatever they were complaining about. So how I can fix whatever this new warning is complaining about?

Comment: You can only do if you would change the `memoir` code. Don't do that. Just live with the warning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the questions:

1. [Table of code listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28712/table-of-code-listings)
2. [How to silence memoir class warning against the use of caption package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391993/how-to-silence-memoir-class-warning-against-the-use-of-caption-package?noredirect=1#comment973963_391993)
3. [How to create a box with caption and label like a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306568/how-to-create-a-box-with-caption-and-label-like-a-float)

You can use the following code for suppressing the warning, as the warning is only documentation on how to use the `memoir`'s class, instead of something you should be fixing.

> Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class. To prepare we will now reset all captioning macros and configurations to kernel defaults, and then let the caption package take over. Please remember to use the caption package interfaces in order to configure your captions.

Noticing know on you need to ignore the caption documentation from the `memoir`'s class and use the caption documentation from the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter*{memoir}{You are using the caption package with the memoir class}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{code}[Code Listing][List of Code Listings]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\listofcodes

    \begin{code}
        \begin{lstlisting}
            Some source code
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption[This here is a caption]{caption}
    \end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]